# React flexbox compatibility with ie 10

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

I am making a flexbox in React and can get it to work in all browsers except IE10. I've tried so many combinations I feel like I'm just guessing now.

Anyone see the problem?

```
const innerToolbarStyle = {
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  width: '100%'
}

<div style= {innerToolbarStyle}>
    {item(Search, props, {margin: 'auto', flex: 1, paddingRight: 10})}
    {item(FilterToggle, props, {margin: 'auto', paddingRight: 10})}
    {item(Sorter,       props, {margin: 'auto', paddingRight: 10})}
    {item(AdminOptions, props, {margin: 'auto'})}
<div style={{clear: 'right'}} />
```

Comment: Can you describe what goes wrong in IE10?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code *and* accurately describe the problem.  "can't get it to work" is not a problem description.  What *does* happen?

Answer (score 1):

**IE 10 does not support the current Flexbox standard**, only an older incomplete version with `-ms-` prefix.

Refer to the [MDN Browser Compatiblity matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility) for more info.

> Internet Explorer 10 supports an old incompatible draft version of the specification; Internet Explorer 11 has been updated to support the final version.